# How to do a --nodeps in a yum_package resource in Chef?

Tags: chef-infra, yum

Is there a way to use yum_package resource that mimics an "rpm -ivh --nodeps" command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Via http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/NoDeps:

> Rpm offers command line options --nodeps and --force. They are
>   intended to allow the admin to put pkgs in place despite conflicting
>   files, unresolved dependencies or just about anything else.
>
> Yum does not implement these options in any way due to the destructive nature of what these options are capable of doing.

You can use rpm_package directly though.

Comment: Though not the answer I was looking for, it seems to be the correct answer. I'll have to do something else for a certain RPM. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, the info at that link doesn't say what the options *actually do* - The "blow them all away" for example - blow "what" all away?  I want to try to install a single package while ignoring a dependency, which I don't think will be a problem, as it is very close.  If I am wrong, I can remove the new package.  I don't want to "blow away" anything else, of course - just install this one package/files so I can try it.  Yum won't let me do that, unless I force it to - somehow - but which option?  Not clear from Yum's instructions.

Comment: The link is the Yum documentation stating that there is no such option, you need to use raw `rpm -i --nodeps` (via `rpm_package` in the case of Chef).